# Would B & CG be a good candidate to replace the GameSquad forum "Advanced Squad Leader Rules & Errata"?

Tags: discussion, questions

To all ASL enthusiasts (and others). While it may seem arrogant to question a set standard, it is certainly not meant that way.

The current [ASL Rules & Errata GameSquad forum](http://forums.gamesquad.com/forumdisplay.php?38-ASL-Rules-amp-Errata) contains a massive amount of knowledge about the rules of the ASL system. Because of this, it serves as an important source of information within the community. However, the "serial" character of the classic forum concept has some disadvantages in certain cases of which the following are most important:

- Threads often wander off-topic
- It's difficult to distill the final answer from long threads due to replies that are not answers to the questions
- It's difficult to see if there IS a final answer to a question at all
- Tagging is not possible

In my opinion the stackexchange concept is a much better way to build a knowledge base of ASL rules questions, that has more value on the long run. And with having more value I mean not having the disadvantages mentioned above.

**Argument(s) in favor:**

- The stackexchange concept (voted answer, reputation system, meta site, etc. etc.) instead of the classic forum concept

**Argument(s) against:**

- B & CG "generic" tags cannot be used for "ASL specific" tagging, so it's useless for that purpose
- The rules questions will be separate from the other ASL GameSquad forums
- There's already too much knowledge in the current forum
- The current forum just works

Your opinions would be welcome.

N.B.: This proposal only concerns the Rules & Errata forum, the others are fine as they are.

Answer (score 4):

> the "serial" character of the classic forum concept has some disadvantages

If those are the things you're trying to defeat, that's *exactly* what we created this software to defeat, too, so it is a very good match.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Board & Card Games Stack Exchange would be a better way to do the rule Q&A, but you're right that there's so much information on the GameSquad forum that it will take a long time to build this up.

Guess we better get started.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that ASL is a good fit for the SE Philosophy, but the amount of material would overwhelm B&CG. Is anyone interested in starting an ASL site in Area 51?

Comment: Don't try to start a new SE site, if the Go and Chess proposals are any indication, it will take over a year to get off the ground.  Use B&CG, try to overwhelm us.  I dare you :)

Comment: @TimLymington - This has been attempted already in the recent past. By me actually. However, it was not considered a good idea by the Area 51 moderators. There are some threads related to this on the meta sites, if you're interested in the backgrounds.