# Games-specific tagging convention.

Tags: discussion, tagging

We already have lots of tags for specific games, but if we generate the levels of traffic we'd like to generate, then we're likely to find that **for the most popular games** people will want/need game-specific tags.

Where there is a lot of traffic relating to a particular game, it would make sense to have multiple tags for that game that would enable users of the site to separate and manage the traffic.

I suggest that we adopt the convention that a tag that is specific to a game should have the name of the game or an abbreviation of the name, then a . and then the tag, so for instance we might have [asl.movement](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asl.movement) for movement in the Advanced Squad Leader games.  Game tags should continue to be the full name of the game, so [advanced-squad-leader](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advanced-squad-leader).

The reason to do this is that it puts them into separate namespaces so you can have [asl.movement](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asl.movement) and [wif.movement](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wif.movement) instead of mixing up everything relating to that phase.

I'm not sure that "movement" is necessarily a good tag, it's just the first example that came to mind!

This came out of a discussion in the comments to [this](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/423/would-b-cg-be-a-good-candidate-to-replace-the-gamesquad-forum-advanced-squad-l/429#429) answer, for context.

Comment: @Dori I think It would be useful for people having the full-game-name tag as one of their favorite tags. They could still view all questions from one game together.

Comment: @Dori - I would think that using the full name should attract more folks from Google.  ASL -> American Sign Language to most of the world.

Comment: @Dori - That would only select all questions with a specific tag. There might still be questions for a game without such a specific tag. Selecting them together is not possible while, please correct me if i'm wrong, OR-ing favorite tags is not possible.

Comment: @Dori - Did not know about the tag sets feature. Thanx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are absolutely 100% right that tagging should focus on using the forms of the tag that are found in Google! This is extremely important.

However, I must say I am not a fan of this "let's smush two things together with a period to ghetto up a tag hierarchy" approach.

I think [advanced-squad-leader](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advanced-squad-leader) should suffice, really.

Considering there is all of one question in this tag at the moment, perhaps it would be a good idea to table this and wait until there are a bunch of questions that might need additional categorization? (Though I'd say you would need 250-500 to even begin needing anything beyond a simple single tag).

Comment: Agreed on the "table until there are lots of questions" proposal.

Comment: Concur.  It's dangerous to solve problems you haven't encountered yet; it means you can't test your solution and find out what you *didn't* think of.

Answer (score 1):

I think in the question's example that you would tag it, [advanced-squad-leader](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advanced-squad-leader) [tactics.movement](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tactics.movement), though I'm not sure that will work well in practice, since tactical considerations tend to overlap a lot.

I think more specific game tags should be based on game versions, like [napoleonic-wars](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/napoleonic-wars) and [napoleonic-wars-2](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/napoleonic-wars-2).

Comment: I have no objection to tagging versions of games.  Over at RPG, there are a plethora of Dungeons and Dragons tags.

Comment: and Gaming has a ton of game-version tags: we don't tend to get too many questions about a series, but rather questions about specific games in the series, so you can follow `fallout*` but also know from the tags which game (or games) are applicable for a given question.